How to transition to a new data point in a realtime line chart using D3 React?
I am trying to build a realtime line chart using d3 and react. Currently I am generating dummy realtime data using setinterval. The chart does update but there is no transition or animation. Can anybody please help me? I want the animation to look like this.
Detrade
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
    select,
    line,
    curveCardinal,
    scaleLinear,
    axisBottom,
    axisLeft,
} from "d3";

const LineChart = () => {
    const svgRef = useRef();

    const generateData = () => {
      return Array.from({ length: 50 }, (_, i) => ({
        x: i,
        y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
      }));
    };

    const [data, setData] = useState(generateData());

    useEffect(() => {
      const svg = select(svgRef.current);

      const width = svgRef.current.parentElement.clientWidth;
      const height = svgRef.current.parentElement.clientHeight - 240;
      const chartHeight = height - 40;
      const marginTop = 70;

      const xScale = scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, data.length - 1])
        .range([0, width - 500]);

      const yScale = scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]).range([chartHeight, 0]);

      const xAxis = axisBottom(xScale).ticks(data.length);
      svg
        .select(".x-axis")
        .style("transform", `translateY(${chartHeight}px)`)
        .call(xAxis);

      const yAxis = axisLeft(yScale);
      svg.select(".y-axis").style("transform", "translateX(0px)").call(yAxis);

      const myLine = line()
        .x((d, i) => xScale(i))
        .y((d) => yScale(d.y))
        .curve(curveCardinal);

      svg
        .selectAll(".line")
        .data([data])
        .join("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", myLine)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "#ffffff")
        .attr(
          "transform",
          `translate(0,${(height - chartHeight) / 2 + marginTop})`
        );

      // Add circle at the end of the line
      const lastDataPoint = data[data.length - 1];
      svg
        .selectAll(".circle")
        .data([lastDataPoint])
        .join("circle")
        .attr("class", "circle")
        .attr("cx", xScale(lastDataPoint.x - 1))
        .attr("cy", yScale(lastDataPoint.y))
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("fill", "#ffffff")
        .attr(
          "transform",
          `translate(0,${(height - chartHeight) / 2 + marginTop})`
        );

      // Add new data point every one second
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setData((prevData) => [
          ...prevData.slice(1),
          { x: prevData.length, y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) },
        ]);
      }, 1000);

      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [data]);

    return (
      <svg ref={svgRef} width="100%" height="100%" style={{ display: "block" }} />
    );
};

export default LineChart;

